# Not understanding how modules in angularjs work together

Tags: angularjs

I'm clearly missing something basic in how modules work and can be used together.  Below, I've created a trivial angular app with ng-app='baseapp' in my html.  x gets the 4 integers correctly in the first controller.

My thinking is that if I create a new module 'mainApp' and make a dependency for that module baseApp that I then can use testService in a controller in baseApp.

I'm guessing there is a lot wrong with what i've done but it is amazing I can get lost in so few lines of code.  Any guidance here is very much appreciated in how to actually create a new module that will let me use a service defined in a previously created module.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';


    var baseApp = angular.module('baseApp', []);
    baseApp.service('testService', function () {
        this.myData = function () {
            return [1, 2, 3, 4];
        }
    });
    baseApp.controller('myBaseController', function (testService) {
        var x = testService.myData();
        console.log('baseApp ' + x.length);
    });


    var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['baseApp']);
    mainApp.controller('myMainController',['testService', function (testService) {
        debugger;
        var y = testService.myData();
        console.log('baseApp ' + y.length);
    }]);


  }());
```

Comment: Did you check you console, possible issue could be the syntax error caused by accessing variable `x` which has not been defined yet. `x.length` inside the myMainController. Otherwise this should just work fine as is and the controller will be instantiated only if you are using it anywhere.

Comment: I fixed the typo and created a plnkr to see the error.  http://plnkr.co/edit/UeQ0nsIpYVoUkpw37lZk?p=preview which is  Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myMainController' is not a function, got undefined.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vUUb9yEHnFxRLZrAkwMl?p=preview Your ngApp should be `mainApp` not `baseApp`. mainApp since it already includes baseApp both the controllers will be available if you just bootstrap your rootelement with mainApp as opposed to having baseApp which only has `myBaseController`. Try the plunker and give it a try

Comment: thanks, that makes sense.  I thought I had blown some fundamental understanding of how modules worked together.

Comment: np you are on the right path, i'd say. :)